# Multi Clearpath Husky Humble Simulation

Tags: gazebo, ros-humble, clearpath

I'm trying to spawn multiple Husky UGV's using the simulation package provided by clearpath. I'm able to spawn one husky and it works as intended. As outlined in the documentation, this default husky has the files for the generators in

```
~/clearpath
```

I created a second directory

```
~/clearpath_r2
```

where I put a different robot.yaml file, this .yaml differs in serial_number/self/platform/namespace. When I run

```
ros2 launch clearpath_gz robot_spawn.launch.py setup_path:=~/clearpath_r2/ x:=3.0 y:=-1.0
```

The second husky shows up in gazebo where it's supposed to be, most of the topics are visible, but the `joint_state_broadcaster` and `platform_velocity_controller` do not seem to start properly.

[image]

The log files don't provide any more details as to what is the actual error in launching these nodes. Any ideas on what to look for or try would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the logs (usually at $HOME/:ros or in colcon under logs/) to see if there more information about the problem? Just brainstorming but if spawning one worked fine and the second have problems might be a name collision somewhere in the controllers not prepared to be multi-robot?

Comment: The logs showed the same as the cmd line there.